# How to switch back to default view after switching to camera view in blender 2.92

Tags: 3d-view, camera, viewlayers

I am using the awesome Blender 3d Software

I can switch to camera view using ctrl+alt+0

[image]

But how to switch back to normal view which was earlier before navigating to camera view

Answer (score 1):

Pressing ~ on keyboard gives you a pie menu:

[image]

View camera in that pie menu acts as a toggle. just select it again to go back to last view.

Comment: In blender 2.93 ` (back tick) works to bring up that menu. Then, choosing View Camera switches between the camera view and the previous view (what OP calls "normal view").

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the question, but the hints given here with switching the layout and using the pie menu make me think I'm completely wrong. What I read in your question is, you were navigating in the *3D Viewport* and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. This is the shortcout for *Align Active Camera to View*. This means, your camera is aligned to what you see in the viewport in that moment and this is the new camera view.

Usually you only have to press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to switch between *Camera Perspective* and the normal navigation view, the *User Perspective*. Let's say the camera's looking on the left side of an object, and you navigate your view to the right side. <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> switches between left and right side view.

My problem is now to understand what you exactly want. <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> gets you to camera view and back to what it was before, you can toggle between them. This doesn't work if you move the viewport when in camera view, because it exits *Camera Perspective* and becomes the new *User Perspective*.

If however your camera is now looking differently at the scene than before, that's because you used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. This moves the camera to a different location and rotation to fit the *Camera Perspective* to the active *User Perspective*. Switching views doesn't get your old camera view back because your camera is no longer in the same location as it was before.

To get it back the only thing you can do is *Undo* your action with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but as all undo actions this only works as long as you didn't do too much inbetween or didn't close and re-open your file.

Answer (score 1):

Blender ships with **a wonderful add-on** called ***Stored Views*** that can save and restore the current point of view (POV) in the viewport.

Just enable it in the preferences:
[image: add-ons / preferences]

After activation, you will find a menu in the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel.
The button <kbd>*Save Current*</kbd> saves the current POV in a new list slot. You can give it a name and restore it later by pressing the cube icon in front of its name.

It also allows you to create a camera from the POV with a single click. That's a convenient shortcut for *Add Camera* and setting the camera to the POV with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

[image: stored views add-on]

Furthermore, you can switch cameras from the list and keyframe them in the timeline. And if you enable the feature in the preferences with the button <kbd>*Enable I/O Operators*</kbd> you can import & export the stored views. Give it a try.

Comment: Stored Views is a good addon!